# Is Laravel 8 Testing with a database broken out of the box

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, testing, phpunit

I have a new Laravel 8 install, running on docker with sail. Everything seems to run fine, but tests that use any configuration seem to be broken.  For example a simple test that pulls a user out of the database fails.

I am using the default phpunit.xml, and I added a .env.testing, which is just a copy of .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Added a quick test to the unit ExampleTest.php

```
/**
 * A basic test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testBasicTest()
{
    $user = User::find(1);
    $this->assertInstanceOf(User::class, $user);
}
```

Run **sail php artisan test**
Tests:  1 failed, 16 passed
Time:   2.70s

```
• Tests\Unit\ExampleTest > basic test
   Error 

  Call to a member function connection() on null

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1493
    1489▕      * @return \Illuminate\Database\Connection
    1490▕      */
    1491▕     public static function resolveConnection($connection = null)
    1492▕     {
  ➜ 1493▕         return static::$resolver->connection($connection);
    1494▕     }
    1495▕ 
    1496▕     /**
    1497▕      * Get the connection resolver instance.
```

I have a number of laravel apps that run these exact same test in previous versions of Laravel.  What am I missing?

Thanks,

Comment: what does it say on you `phpunit.xml` on the database section? What testcase are you extending from?

Comment: Its the same as https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/phpunit.xml,
<!-- <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/> -->
<!-- <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
 which is not set, so I am assuming it should fall back to the .env.testing file.

Comment: The commands at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#running-tests look different

Comment: I believe "sail php artisan test" === "sail artisan test" === "sail test", I get the same result anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You sure you're using a fresh `phpunit.xml` and `.env`?

I found `backupGlobals="false" backupStaticAttributes="false"` was killing some vars at `$_ENV` and `$_SERVER`, and a nasty component was reading variables from there.

What I did was expose `.env` and `phpunit.xml` to `phpunit` inside a tests and test its values. Found out that you cannot read with `env('key')` the data at `/.env` (*phpunit* environment variables are different of what you configure inside `.env` and `phpunit.xml`), which apply only to the tested application.

Installing a fresh version of Laravel 8 on a new project and comparing my tree with the fresh one showed me I was also missing some `.env` definitions and that had an overbloated `phpunit.xml` file.